# how to fetch the meta field keys/meta boxes from a post type?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-type

I need to find all the meta keys or meta boxes preferably from just a post type ...couldn't find any wordpress function to do this. Any custom queries?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) will return all the meta_key => meta_value pairs for a given post.  It returns the fields in sort of a weird format, however.

eg.

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_custom(1);

/*
$meta would be...

arrary(
   'some_meta_key' => array(
       'one_meta_value'
   )
);
*/
```

Unless you mean get all meta for all posts in a given post type, for that you'll need a custom query.

```
<?php
function wpse65225_get_all_meta($type)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE post_id IN
        (SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s)", $type
    ), ARRAY_A);

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying...What I have is a meta box set for a particular custom post type...So I just wanted to grab the meta field keys that custom post type supports..I don't need to work with post ids...just the post type.. Any ideas?

Comment: post types can support any meta keys.  The metadata api doesn't restrict anything like that. There are meta keys that the core uses, but they aren't really documented.